# Unable to import packages from another package

Tags: python, pytest

I have the following directory tree structure

```
Directory of E:\project

07-11-2021  10:30    <DIR>          .
07-11-2021  10:30    <DIR>          ..
07-11-2021  10:30    <DIR>          app
07-11-2021  10:44    <DIR>          tests

dir app\hello\


07-11-2021  10:32    <DIR>          .
07-11-2021  10:32    <DIR>          ..
07-11-2021  10:31                52 hello.py
07-11-2021  10:32                 0 __init__.py
```

hello.py has a function called greeting.

Now from my Tests folder I want to import hello.py module and the function greeting and test it.
But looks like it's not working and I am getting an error.

```
ImportError while importing test module 'E:\project\tests\test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
C:\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py:126: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test.py:1: in <module>
    from app import hello
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

What am i missing here please

Tried with relative imports also VS Code does not complain but Python surely is yelling at me :).

[image]

Finally resolved it .
After spending 4 hours on the net the solution requires me to use something like

```
E:\project
python -m tests.test
Guten Morning
```

Not sure this is the best practice but its working for now.

Comment: [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sys-path-in-python/) might help you.

Comment: Read up on relative imports.

Comment: Hi MattDMo thanks for the advice I am surely missing something obvious here.Hello Mohil thanks for the link but sliglthy cautious on modifying paths

Comment: Have you tried using this: `from app.hello.hello import greeting`. Btw, I think this is called absolute importing

Comment: Hi Asian Cat Thanks for taking a look at this when i try absolute import i get ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'